# Significantly slower DB queries between Ruby 2.7.6 (heroku-20) and Ruby 3.1.4 (heroku-22)

Tags: ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres, ruby-3

I have a Ruby 2.7.6 app running on Heroku (stack heroku-20) and a branch of the same app on Ruby 3.1.4 running on Heroku (stack heroku-22). Both have identical DBs. Running these two branches locally, DB query times seem similar. However on Heroku, DB queries on the Ruby 3 build are massively (sometimes over 10x) slower.

```
# Ruby 2.7.6 on Heroku-20
participant_registration.session_results.count
D, [2023-07-15T15:10:25.598762 #2] DEBUG -- :    (85.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "session_results" WHERE "session_results"."sessionable_id" = $1 AND "session_results"."sessionable_type" = $2  [["sessionable_id", 82497], ["sessionable_type", "UserChampionship"]]

# Ruby 3.1.4 on Heroku-22
participant_registration.session_results.count
D, [2023-07-15T15:10:43.115159 #2] DEBUG -- :    (1167.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "session_results" WHERE "session_results"."sessionable_id" = $1 AND "session_results"."sessionable_type" = $2  [["sessionable_id", 82497], ["sessionable_type", "UserChampionship"]]
```

*All* queries are significantly slower, I just chose this one as it seemed even more dramatic than others. Perhaps this is a question I need to raise with Heroku, but I just wanted to check if there was something else I am missing here that I should be aware of.

**UPDATE**
Turns out something must have just gone wrong with the DB on this particular environment. After deleting and rebuilding (with the same production data), it's snappy again.

Comment: Did you spin up the database in the same region as the dyno?

Comment: @spickermann unsure, not sure how to control that on Heroku. I should point out though, if i were to roll back our Heroku-22 environment back to Heroku-20 and Ruby 2, query times would be fast again, so i'm not sure it'd be a region issue.

Comment: Is it the same application and DB on Heroku, that you updated to Stack-22 and Ruby 3. Or did you create a new application with a new DB for the new environment?

Comment: It's a branch of the same application (only difference being the Ruby version change). DBs are both identical copies from our production environment.

Comment: I would try [connecting directly to the database with a PostgreSQL client](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-psql) and running both queries directly against the DB without Rails.

Comment: Well that's super interesting; the speed differential is still present when querying directly on the DB... [big thinking emoji]

Comment: @spickermann well well well. I deleted and rebuilt the DB on the slow environment, and all is zippy again! No idea what happened there. Thanks for helping me think through that.